# Is it possible to implement a filter to make dark images appear illuminated?

Tags: image, image-processing, camera, filtering, frame-rate

I am working on an image processing project. Faster I process the images, the better. However as I increase the fps of my camera, everything begin to appear darker, since the camera do not have enough time to receive light. I was wondering if I could find a way around of this issue, since I know what is causing it.

I am thinking of writing a code that will increase all pixel values proportionally with what camera returns. Since only difference is the time duration, I think there should be a linear proportion between pixel values and the time duration camera had while taking that picture.

Before trying this, I have searched if there is anything available online but failed to find any. It feels like this is a basic concept so I would be surprised if no one had done such a thing before, so I might be using wrong keywords.

So my question is, is there a filter or an algorithm that increases the "illumination" of a dark image (since shot at high fps). If not, does what I intend to do make sense?

Comment: what is it you want to achieve in your processing?

Comment: I am going to track a fast motion at high fps. Computationally I think I can make it feasible by parallel processing etc, however I was not able to get clear images in a high frame rate (that is 60-90 fps)

Comment: tracking will not benefit from any image enhancement you are asking for as you only have a given amount of information. you cannot add any new useful information by image processing. it won't improve your result if you alter that information in any way.

Comment: I cannot add new information, but this is about how to make best use of the information I already have using reasonable assumptions such as noise band limiting and linearly approximating the real intensities (as since there should be a relation between intensities that are generated with duration t and duration 2t). In other words I think it might be possible because I am trying to approximate rather than have a crystal clear result.

Comment: yes but it does not matter. lets say you have 2 different values. 1 and 2. you don't want to process 1 and 2 so you change your image. then you have 4 and 8. ok your image is brighter now, but 4 is still 50% of 8 and that is the information you can use. so why spend the time creating artificial data that does not add any value?

Comment: methods for contrast improvement always target the human eye because we cannot distinguish between very similar gray values. so you change the gray value distribution in a way that it becomes easier for us. you computer has no issues seeing the difference between gray values 200 and 201... just keep that in mind

Comment: I get your point. Thanks a lot for the insight, I was not aware of what you have just suggested.

Comment: just check youtube for high speed camera applications, they always require a LOT of light :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Histogram Equalization here, rather than increasing all the pixels by some constant factor. Histogram Equalization makes the the probability of all possible pixel intensity equal thus enhancing the image.

Read about it using the following links

http://www.math.uci.edu/icamp/courses/math77c/demos/hist_eq.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Read this article on how to do it in opencv, 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html

Comment: That was a quite useful suggestion, I will definitely try that out. Thanks!

Comment: And just curious, what is the disadvantage of increasing all pixel values by a constant factor? Is it about noise? If yes, can I try that with a bandpass filter to try eliminating noise then?

Comment: I suppose you can do that but wont result in a good image, as you would have already tried. The mentioned method improves contrast.

Comment: @OE1 this approach only inproves perception by the human eye. it will not help you at all if you are just tracking an object like stated above

Answer (score 0):

If your image is too dark use more light. That would be the proper way.

Of course you can increase brightness values but the image by simply multiplying them with a factor or adding an offset. Or spreading the histogram.

Instead of a bad dark image you'll end up with a bad bright image.

Low contrast, low dynamic range, low signal to noise ratio, all of that won't change.

Comment: The medium I experiment is reasonably illuminated and all images I take are quite clear except when I increase the frame rate. Since sensors do not have enough time to receive light, I am pretty much stuck with digital processing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @OE1 yes but increasing frame rate decreases exposure time. therefor you have to increase illumination to obtain the same brightness...
if you cannot increase illumination you have the problem that you can't add information by processing. you are stuck with the little information you have.